# TextView not positioning under ImagevVew in `CoordinatorLayout`

Tags: java, android, android-coordinatorlayout

I am developing android news app. and in my list, I have implemented image and  `TextView` however I cant put `TextView` below `ImageView`.  I have Googled it did not found useful info.

Below my `CoordinatorLayout` example:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/articleImage"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="185dp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@id/articleAuthor"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/article_author"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the code over here -> https://www.androidauthority.com/using-coordinatorlayout-android-apps-703720/.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.sample.foo.usingcoordinatorlayout.FabAndSnackbarActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:title="@string/collapsing_toolbar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/bg"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:text="@string/long_latin"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/mascot_icon"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues with your XML.

1. There is an extra `LinearLayout` tag that is never closed, so this shouldn't even build. You shouldn't need this and should be able to delete it.
2. If you want the `TextView` below the `ImageView` you need to set constraints on the `TextView` so it does just that.

So at minimum, you need something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" // <- App namespace
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/articleImage"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="185dp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@id/articleAuthor"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/article_author"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/articleImage" /> // <- Constraint

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I strongly recommend reviewing the `ConstraintLayout` documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout

Hope that helps!
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#0

Comment: "layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf" works like a charm when you want to place view under appbar in coordinatorlayout

Answer (score 0):

The layout maybe like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.club.detail.ActivityTopicDetail"
    >

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/cus_appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/articleImage"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="185dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<TextView
     android:id="@id/articleAuthor"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/article_author"
     app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```